# What is the difference between these two in Rust?

Tags: rust, tuples, destructuring

I'm learning Rust and came across the following:

```
let (x, y, z);
(x, y, z) = (1, 2, 3);
```

Is there any difference between that and this, besides the former being more compact?

```
let x;
let y;
let z;
(x, y, z) = (1, 2, 3);
```

Finally, risking being told that that's just how Rust's syntax is, is there any reason why the following doesn't work?

```
let x, y, z;
(x, y, z) = (1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Questions about the syntax of a language can usually always be answered by looking into its reference... [let statements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/statements.html#let-statements).

Comment: cause not initialize a variable should be avoid if possible, honestly they very very few case where you can't init a variable, and I think with maybeunit there is almost none now, multiline let are pretty much useless and could help people do bad code like show in your question.

Comment: @Stargateur, Thank you for the advice. I am aware that the idiomatic way to do it is to initialize a variable when declaring it, and that Rust will throw an error when attempting to use a variable without initializing it first. However, my question was more about why the parentheses are necessary and whether defining them in a single let statement as if they were a tuple is equivalent to defining them using one let statement per variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are spot on already in the question this is [how let works in Rust syntax works](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/statements.html#let-statements).

Typically you don't declare your variables in the top of the function and assign them later as in traditional c, but instead use let to declare and assign at the same time.

```
let a = 1;
let b = (2,3);
let (x, y, z) = (1, 2, 3);
```

The most common use of `let` is to create one unmutlable variable one time, here you have encountered the slightly more advanced feature in the syntax where it will also accept a tuple of variables `(x,y,z)` and create or assign them at the same time.

The rust compiler is very helpfull in explaining what needs to be done:

When we try the c inspired syntax

```
let x, y, z; // Incorrect
```

We get a description on how to solve the issue

```
error: unexpected `,` in pattern
 --> src/main.rs:2:9
  |
2 |    let x, y, z;
  |         ^
  |
help: try adding parentheses to match on a tuple
  |
2 |    let (x, y, z);
  |        +       +
```

Comment: "you have encountered the slightly more advanced feature in the syntax where it will also accept a tuple of variables"; Tuples aren't some special case here, `let` statements let you assign to any valid, irrefutable pattern.

Comment: @isaactfa: And `let`/`else` even allows refutable patterns.